# I set up and scheduled a mailing, but it didn't send. Now what?

Tags: civimail, mailing

I scheduled a mailing to send according the the instructions, and it didn't send. Now what?

Comment: There are a number of possible reasons for this.  What CMS and what version of Civi are you using?  Are you able to send a test email from that scheduled mailing?  Can you send individual mailings to individual contacts?  Please let us know some more details of your situation.

Answer (score 2):

This has happened to me in the past for a few reasons

- In one instance, my time zone was set wrong so the scheduled time had already passed, and the mailing was never triggered.
- My cron jobs weren't running. A temporary fix would be to trigger the job manually in Administer > System Settings > Scheduled Jobs > Send Scheduled Mailings.
- My cron job hadn't run yet. For example, I can schedule my email to go out at 1:15, but if my cron jobs run every hour it won't go out until 2:00.